# Runtime Error in JavaHelp

Tags: java, runtime-error, javahelp

This is an issue that I have been running into for months and have been unable to solve it. We have continued to develop our JavaHelp; however, we are at a point where this needs to be fixed and I am out of ideas.

What this is: A Java Application

Folder structure:

```
-src
--HelpsetProject.java //Main method to launch JavaHelp
--help-hs.xml
--help-idx.xml
--help-map.xml
--help-toc.xml
--Images/ //images folder
--Topics/ //Topics folder for html files
```

The issue:

The application builds and compiles fine. It launches and runs fine, displaying the help as intended. However, fairly often when launched, the left side (item list/tree) will have a blank line or will be completely blank:

[image: Blank list tree]

I originally thought that this issue was caused by missing map-toc tags, mistyped/mismatched xml tags/elements and general typos, as I am not the one actually creating these. However, I went over the files, validated and checked XML, double checked that all items on the list link to a file and clicked on every item in the list to see that it displays. The issue still persists, unless I missed something.

Here is the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/MetalWing/JavaHelp):

Here you can [download](http://nexrem.com/Helpset.jar) the executable and run it several times to see the error for yourself (It really is a chance for it to work/not work):